# Adding shapes at different pages of a MS Word Document in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, anchor

I am currently working on a .NET- Application in Visual Studio 2010. I want to create a MS Word 2010-file using C#. I have already created a new document and inserted some paragraphs. Now I want to insert some shapes in the document. Therefore I use the Word.Document.Shapes.AddLine()-method in the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace. I want to add the shapes after certain paragraphs. Everything works when these paragraphs are on the first page of the document. But if the paragraph is on another page the shape will also be inserted at the first page. I use the following C#-code:

```
//Add paragraph
Word.Paragraph oPara2;
object oRng = NewDocument.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
oPara2= NewDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
oPara2.Range.Text = "Text";      
oPara2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

//Vertical position of the shape
float position = (float) (oPara2.Range.get_Information (Word.WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) - 16.5 );
//Add Line
Word.Shape line2 = NewDocument.Shapes.AddLine(30, position, 800, position);

/* 
*
*Some more paragraphs
*
**/
//Next Paragraph with shape
Word.Paragraph oPara13;
oRng = NewDocument.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
oPara13 = NewDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
oPara13.Range.Text = "Text";      
oPara13.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

//Vertical position of the shape
position = (float) (oPara13.Range.get_Information (Word.WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) - 16.5 );
//Add Line
Word.Shape line3 = NewDocument.Shapes.AddLine(30, position, 800, position);
```

The paragraph oPara13 is on the second page of the document. The calculated position value is correct but the shape will be inserted at the first page at this position. Now I want to ask how to make the shape be inserted at the correct page where the corresponding paragraph is. I have already tried to set the anchor parameter of the AddLine method but with bad results.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if all you need is generating .docx files, cosider using the OpenXML project. It'll work much faster and will not suffer from issues related with working with Word (like multithreading, files not closed properly or licensing). Generating documents with OpenXML is not trivial, but it becomes much easier if you use the productivity tool - it lets you open any document and generates c# code that would recreate it.

Regarding your question, word inserts it exactly where you ask it - the function receives an absolute vertical coordinates and the coordinates you provide point to the first page. 
So instead of using wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage use wdVerticalPositionRelativeToTextBoundary, in the case of regular of normal text it will give you the absolute coordinate. Or you can get the position of the last paragraph

```
absoluteY= ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToTextBoundary)  

ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddLine(50, absoluteY, 150, absoluteY).Select
```

Another note - if you're not sure how to perform something, open Word and record a macro of you doing it. The generated code is very enlightening. You'll notice Word uses select and Selection a lot.

Answer (score -1):

This answer doesn't work for me. But I did some research and found this solution:

The method `Shapes.AddLine` uses the known 4 parameter coordinates. But there is a 5th parameter. This is the anchor!

The Anchor is in this case the new range of a paragraph of your text.
It always takes the first paragraph of the current page. From there you can add the new coordinates:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, <your paragraph>.Range).Select;
```